# Frequently rendering useEffect in react component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

In my last project, i found an issue, when i call and put sth between brackets, i got an error in browser which says:

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjNyp.png).

i don't know what should i do to solve it!

```js
 useEffect(() => {
    GetRestaurantCategories(restaurantID, (restaurantCategories) => {
      setCategories(
        restaurantCategories.map(
          (category: {
            categoryId: string;
            restaurantId: string;
            categoryName: string;
          }) => {
            return {
              value: category.categoryId,
              label: category.categoryName
            };
          }
        )
      );
    });
  }, []);
```

i put this pseudo code in initial lines of the component to first render the useEffect and after do sth.
but browser run the useEffect multi time... and i got error.

Comment: can you please share code in which you are having above given error.

Comment: Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.  We don't know what you should do to solve it either because we can't see your code. It's like going to an auto mechanic and saying "my car doesn't work; here's a picture of the car not moving."

Comment: We can't help you at all if all you provide is a picture of the error. We can't help diagnose or debug what we can't see. Please edit your post to include the error as plainly formatted and readable text, include the code stacktrace if you can, and provide the code causing the issue as a [mcve].

Comment: Error image link is attached

Comment: please, post code where error is occured

Answer (score 0):

**Please search first at google for your question.**

the `useEffect` is receiving 2 argument

1. a callback function
2. an argument to update

like I see in your picture I think, you forget to put an argument there,
if you don't want to update the argument you can put it in an empty array

so please use the `useEffect` like this

```
 useEffect(() => {
    // your CODE
    console.log("this is example");
}, []) //<<<
```

please look carefully at the example

and check this documentation
https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-useeffect-explanation/